# ¿Cómo ver los datos de de una consulta a PostgreSQL en R?

Tags: r

Hice lo siguiente.

```
resultado <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM estado")
```

Pero si pongo `> resultado`, lo que obtengo es:

```
<PostgreSQLResult>
```

¿Cómo puedo ver los valores que obtuve de la consulta?

Mi tabla sólo tiene dos campos, **clave** y **nombre**.

Estoy trabajando con el paquete **RPostgreSQL.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbSendQuery` envía la consulta y te crea un recurso para que puedas interactuar con ella. Para obtener el primer resultado, podés usar `dbFetch`:

```
primer_fila <- dbFetch(resultado, n = 1)
```

Si quisieras cargar todas las filas:

```
todos <- dbFetch(resultado, n = Inf)
```